# How to output results set of every iteration in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, optimization

How do I output the sets of results from each iteration in a new line in the worksheet? i.e looping through all the possible combinations of (i,j,k,l,m)

```
avg protein1 = (0,j,k,l,m) 
avg protein2 = (1,j,k,l,m) 
avg protein3 = (2,j,k,l,m) ... 
.. . 
avg protein (n-2) = (i,j,k,l,0) 
avg protein (n-1) = (i,j,k,l,1) 
avg protein (n) = (i,j,k,l,2)
```

Here's the code from a modified knapsack optimization problem (code works). It maximizes the avg protein value from 5 different bins subject to margin constraint from each bin.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ProteinCalc()
    
    Dim limit As Double, tol As Double, Protein As Double, Margin As Double, averageprotein As Double, maximumMargin As Double
    Dim i, j, k, l, m As Integer
    
    Dim Proteini, Proteinj, Proteink, Proteinl, Proteinm As Double
    Dim Margini, Marginj, Margink, Marginl, Marginm As Double
    
    
    Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("B19:H23").ClearContents
    Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("B4:F4").ClearContents
    
    
    limit = Range("D6").Value                   'declare max protein target on blend
    tol = Range("G6").Value                     'declare tolarance on protein blend to get close to max protien target
    
    maximumMargin = Range("G8").Value          'declare minimum margin $/MT want to make
    
    Proteini = Range("B2").Value
    Proteinj = Range("C2").Value
    Proteink = Range("D2").Value
    Proteinl = Range("E2").Value
    Proteinm = Range("F2").Value
    
    Margini = Range("B3").Value
    Marginj = Range("C3").Value
    Margink = Range("D3").Value
    Marginl = Range("E3").Value
    Marginm = Range("F3").Value
    
    For i = 0 To 2                                                         'loop up to 2 to signify a possible double spot for train at station i
        For j = 0 To 2
            For k = 0 To 2
                For l = 0 To 2
                    For m = 0 To 2
                            Protein = (Proteini * i + Proteinj * j + Proteink * k + Proteinl * l + Proteinm * m) / 5        'linear avg of 5 stations
                            Margin = (Margini * i + Marginj * j + Margink * k + Marginl * l + Marginm * m) / 5              ' linear avg of margin from 5 stations
                            
                            If Margin > maximumMargin And Protein <= limit Then
                                Range("B4").Value = i
                                Range("C4").Value = j
                                Range("D4").Value = k
                                Range("E4").Value = l
                                Range("F4").Value = m
                                averageprotein = Protein
                                maximumMargin = Margin
                              Debug.Print i
                              
                        End If
                                If m >= 0 And m <= 2 Then
                                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("B23").Value = averageprotein
                                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("C23").Value = Proteini
                                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("D23").Value = Proteinj
                                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("E23").Value = Proteink
                                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("F23").Value = Proteinl
                                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("G23").Value = Proteinm
                                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("H23").Value = m
                                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("i23").Value = l
                                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("j23").Value = k
                                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("k23").Value = j
                                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("l23").Value = i
                                
                                End If
                            
                            
                    Next m
                            If l >= 0 And l <= 2 Then
                            Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("B22").Value = averageprotein
                            Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("C22").Value = Proteini
                            Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("D22").Value = Proteinj
                            Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("E22").Value = Proteink
                            Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("F22").Value = Proteinl
                            Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("G22").Value = Proteinm
                            Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("H22").Value = l
                            End If
                    
                Next l
                        If k >= 0 And k <= 2 Then
                        Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("B21").Value = averageprotein
                        Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("C21").Value = Proteini
                        Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("D21").Value = Proteinj
                        Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("E21").Value = Proteink
                        Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("F21").Value = Proteinl
                        Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("G21").Value = Proteinm
                        Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("H21").Value = k
                        End If
                    
            Next k
                    If j >= 0 And j <= 2 Then
                    Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("B20").Value = averageprotein
                    Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("C20").Value = Proteini
                    Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("D20").Value = Proteinj
                    Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("E20").Value = Proteink
                    Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("F20").Value = Proteinl
                    Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("G20").Value = Proteinm
                    Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("H20").Value = j
                    End If
            
        Next j
                If i >= 0 And i <= 2 Then
                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("B19").Value = averageprotein
                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("C19").Value = Proteini
                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("D19").Value = Proteinj
                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("E19").Value = Proteink
                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("F19").Value = Proteinl
                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("G19").Value = Proteinm
                Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("H19").Value = i
                End If
            
    Next i
    
    Range("B6").Value = averageprotein
    Range("B8").Value = maximumMargin
    
End Sub
```

Comment: As VBA code is slow, I would use SQL (is there a problem that can't be easy solved by SQL ;), ok there are some ;() as usual and create a [cartesian product](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-cross-join/) and remove the unwanted dupes in the query critera. That should be much faster than most optimizations on reducing the no of loops. The result can assigned to a sheet with `CopyFromRecordset`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking but you can calculate the line with 81 * i + 27 * j + 9 * k + 3 * l + m + 1

Comment: @Zer0Kelvin want to output "averageprotein = Protein" value for each iteration in the loop. the intergers i,j,k,l,m the formula loops through you can think of them as weights in that formula. does this make sense?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher wish I know SQL...newbie to programming in general (as you can imagine)

Comment: Add some sample data as text formated as [table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and expected output. If newbie working with data sql is a perfect start, as the basicss are far less complicated compared to "normal" programming. If you start with Ms Acccess, no programming is needed and you will later benefit as most Excel users don't use it (as they don't know) but it makes many problems easy to solve and you avoid many problems if you know how to use data. Just serch for some "ms access query tutorials (no froms,reports or code).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to up the row number in every iteration before writing the value to the worksheet. So, declare an iteration counter variable:

```
Dim itrCount As Long
```

then change this:

```
If m >= 0 And m <= 2 Then
   Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("B23").Value = averageprotein
   Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("C23").Value = Proteini
```

to this:

```
If m >= 0 And m <= 2 Then
   itrCount = itrCount + 1
   Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("B23").Offset(itrCount).Value = averageprotein
   Worksheets("simplecalc").Range("C23").Offset(itrCount).Value = Proteini
```

in every loop accordingly.

That's the minimum needed to make it work, there are other improvements you can apply here.